# Python Compare rows in two columns and write a result conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I've been searching for quite a while not not getting anywhere close to what I wanted to do...

I have a pandas dataframe in which I want to compare the value of column A to B and write a 1 or 0 in a new column if A and B are equal.

I could write an ugly for loop but I know this is not very pythony.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this with apply() but I'm not getting anywhere.

I'd like to be able to compare columns that contain integers as well as columns containing strings.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: By 'df' do you mean `DataFrame`? Is this a Pandas question?

Comment: Yes pandas dataframe sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `df` is a Pandas DataFrame, then

```
df['newcol'] = (df['A'] == df['B']).astype('int')
```

For example,

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,'foo'], 'B': [1,99,'foo']})

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
     A    B
0    1    1
1    2   99
2  foo  foo

In [22]: df['newcol'] = (df['A'] == df['B']).astype('int')

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
     A    B  newcol
0    1    1       1
1    2   99       0
2  foo  foo       1
```

---

`df['A'] == df['B']` returns a boolean Series:

```
In [24]: df['A'] == df['B']
Out[24]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

`astype('int')` converts the `True`/`False` values to integers -- 0 for `False` and 1 for `True`.

Comment: How to I instruct python to write 1 or 0 in that new column? And how can I work this out if the content of A and B are strings?

Comment: Yours is better! I had an `.apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)` which is way slower in this case.